# how can i use application/ld+json in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Layout in next js and I use Head component .
I want to use schema json but I have an error.

This is my code:

```
<Head>
        <script type="application/ld+json">
          {{
            "@context": "http://schema.org",
            "@type": "Person",
            address: {
              "@type": "PostalAddress",
              addressLocality: "Seattle",
              addressRegion: "WA",
              postalCode: "98052",
              streetAddress: "20341 Whitworth Institute 405 N. Whitworth"
            },
            colleague: [
              "http://www.xyz.edu/students/alicejones.html",
              "http://www.xyz.edu/students/bobsmith.html"
            ],
            email: "mailto:jane-doe@xyz.edu",
            image: "janedoe.jpg",
            jobTitle: "Professor",
            name: "Jane Doe",
            telephone: "(425) 123-4567",
            url: "http://www.janedoe.com"
          }}
        </script>
</Head>
```

and this is my error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {@context, @type, address, colleague, email, image, jobTitle, name, telephone, url}). 

If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. in script (at Layout.js:130) in head in Head (at _document.js:43) in html in Html (at _document.js:42) in MyDocument in Context.Provider in Context.Provider
```

Please help!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You need to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` in order to put your schema data.

```
<Head>
  <script
    type="application/ld+json"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify(structuredData) }}
  />
</Head>
```

Comment: Note that you still need `JSON.stringify` in the above example.

Comment: I also need to implement structured data into my page, is my page susceptible to cross-site scripting if I use this (dangerouslySetInnerHTML)?

Comment: @TimeParadox Depends where your html is coming from. If it's a 3rd party, yes. If it's just a chunk of data that came from you, no.

Comment: This will not render client-side but only in the backend ssr

Comment: hey, when expecting the elements of the page the script tag should be visible, right?

Comment: @Mihai, it should be visible, since it got SSRed by Next.js

Comment: After putting it in head tag it is not visible any more, previously with head tag, it was visible twice , once from script and second is from next js chunk

Answer (score 12):

```
const addJsonLd = () => {
  return {
    __html: `
     YOUR JSON OBJECT HERE
    `
  }
}

<Head>
    <script
      type="application/ld+json"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={addJsonLd()}
      key="item-jsonld"
    />
</Head>
```

The approach is mentioned in the NextJS docs. [Setting Metadata in NextJS Apps](https://nextjs.org/learn/seo/rendering-and-ranking/metadata)

Comment: FYI we need two underscores but you've written one. `__html`

Answer (score 11):

It's actually recommended to use the Next.js [Script component](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) `next/script` now.

```
import Script from "next/script";

<Head>
    <Script
        type="application/ld+json"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify(jsonData) }}
    />
</Head>
```

Comment: Get an error when doing this: The next/script component should not be used in a next/head component.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the sample structured data snippet you provided. This should solve your problem.
However, if you intend to test your structured data snippet on [google's rich result testing tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results), you will need to use a generic script tag, put keys in double-quotes and exclude the dangerouslySetInnerHTML attribute.

```
<Head>
      <script
        type="application/ld+json"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify({
                "@context": "http://schema.org",
                "@type": "Person",
                address: {
                  "@type": "PostalAddress",
                  addressLocality: "Seattle",
                  addressRegion: "WA",
                  postalCode: "98052",
                  streetAddress: "20341 Whitworth Institute 405 N. Whitworth"
                },
                colleague: [
                  "http://www.xyz.edu/students/alicejones.html",
                  "http://www.xyz.edu/students/bobsmith.html"
                ],
                email: "mailto:jane-doe@xyz.edu",
                image: "janedoe.jpg",
                jobTitle: "Professor",
                name: "Jane Doe",
                telephone: "(425) 123-4567",
                url: "http://www.janedoe.com"
              })
           }}
      />
</Head>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation about your solution.

Comment: Your solution includes the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop.... Also you're not providing the key as suggested in your solution. Also what's a "generic" script tag?

Answer (score 1):

NextJs now provides next/script component to solve this problem,
Insted of using dangerouslySetInnerHTML you can use Script component to add scripts in your component directly, here is an basic example for reference

```
function MyApp() {
  return (
   <>
    <Script>
    {`
      // ** your js goes here
    `}
    </Script>
    <Head>
       seo tags
    </Head>
    <div>
       your jsx or components
    </div>
   <>  
  )

}
```

here is the official documentation link to know more about other features of the tag https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello! Please include more information in your answer. You provided only a link that contain quite a lot of information, it can't be used as it.

Comment: You'll need to specify the `type` prop in the Script component so crawlers understand it as JSON LD: `type="application/ld+json"`

Comment: Next/script HTML-encodes elements like double quotes ("), which ld-json parsers don't seem to like.

Comment: Downvoted as it did not work for me - the `<Script type="application/ld+json">` tag is not in the page source. You should provide a working example with a JSON-LD structure.

Answer (score 0):

There is [**Script** Component](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script) available under `next/script`.

You can simply use it like this :

```
import Script from "next/script";

const idJsonObject = { // Your Object Here }

<Head>
    <Script type="application/ld+json"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify(idJsonObject)}} />
</Head>
```

You can further break it down to :

```
import Script from "next/script";

const idJsonObject = { // Your Object Here }
const idJsonObject = { __html: JSON.stringify(idJsonObject) }

<Head>
    <Script type="application/ld+json"
    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={idJsonObject} />
</Head>
```