# Next.js 13 - How can I add a custom json script tag to each page

Tags: next.js

**Context**

- Using next.js version 13
- Using new `/app` directory
- Using typescript `tsx` etc...

**Goal**

To add `schema.json` within a `<script>` tag on each page:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Thing",
  ...
}
</script>
```

**Solution Attempts**

- Tried using `/head.tsx`, doesn't seem to work for each route
- Tried using the `<Head>` tag, which doesn't seem to be supported in the new `/app` directory
- Tried using `next/script` ([from this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71747719/2419584)) but that seems to load the script on the client, I want it to be added at build-time or on the server
- Tried using the new "[config-based metadata](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/metadata#config-based-metadata)", but it says that "script" tags are not supported...

Any ideas on how to add `<script type="application/ld+json">` server-side for each page?

Answer (score 0):

***For Future Readers***

Okay, seems it's not supported in the head yet ([discussion for feature on  Github](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/44629))

Basically in `next@13.3.1` you need to add the Schema.Org json script tag to the page body, ***not*** to the head

```js
export default function Page() {
  return (
    <>
      <script
        key="schema-jsonld"
        type="application/ld+json"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify(schemaJsonObj, null, "\t") }}
      />
     ....
```

It will still be read by search engines, but hopefully it will be possible to add to the `<head>` soon

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work for my use case; it appends to the head and can be used either in layout or pages

```js
export default function RootLayout() {
          return (
            <>
              <head>
                <script
                  id="schema-jsonld"
                  type="application/ld+json"
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                    __html: JSON.stringify(structuredData, null, "\t"),
                  }}
                />
              </head>
              <html>...</html>
            </>
          );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [the official solution](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata#json-ld):

```
export default async function Page({ params }) {
  const product = await getProduct(params.id)
 
  const jsonLd = {
    '@context': 'https://schema.org',
    '@type': 'Product',
    name: product.name,
    image: product.image,
    description: product.description,
  }
 
  return (
    <section>
      {/* Add JSON-LD to your page */}
      <script
        type="application/ld+json"
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: JSON.stringify(jsonLd) }}
      />
      {/* ... */}
    </section>
  )
}
```